# What is the easiest way to deploy a MVC2 application from Visual Studio 2010 to IIS 7.5?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I´ve tried a couple of different ways to deploy a application to a IIS 7.5 running on my machine for testing purposes and i´ve sort of hit a wall. Nothing works out of the box. Everything assumes I have knowledge I don't have and would prefer not to have to aqquire.

Google isn't really helping either with answers ranging from "copy files by hand" to "install teamcity and set it up for CI". I have set up TeamCity for java projects before and it's really over kill for my needs at the moment.

So anyone know of a fast, simple and easy way to deploy a application during testing/building?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is you should be using the [Web Deploy](http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/) packaging from Visual Studio. The long answer requires learning how to use it, but this post and video should help get you started with [web deploy](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebDeploymentMadeAwesomeIfYoureUsingXCopyYoureDoingItWrong.aspx).

Comment: P.S. Web Deploy is exactly a zip archive of your project with all the IIS settings as metadata.

Comment: Funnily enough as a standard setting it added the WHOLE path when zipping. Hanselman never really got that in his presentation but then again he just mentioned most stuff.

Answer (score 1):

For testing on your own machine just point IIS directly at your MVC project directory. No 'deployment' is needed.

Comment: I´d like something one step "above that" it breaks development and is just a poor solution in general. I guess what I really want is for VS to just deliver a zip-file i can put in the asp.net folder myself.

Comment: How does it 'break development'?  Lots of people work this way.  Once it's building and running OK locally you then check in and have a continuous integration server build and deploy to a test server.  Setting up Teamcity to drop the built bits into a directory that has IIS 7 pointing to it is trivial.

Comment: Just a second ago it locked the filed I wanted to edit, had to shut down the web server just to be able to clean the solution.